# how to pass onOptionsItemSelected item id from Main activity to another activity

Tags: java, android

I want to pass itemId from main activity to another activity.
Now i wrote code like below, But i dont want like this, Just i want pass itemId from this activity to another when option is selected. In another activity i will write switch case option.

Here my code:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



            case R.id.action_settings:SettingsFragment fragmentS = new SettingsFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentS).commit();
                break;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `Intents` ?

Comment: From your code it seems you want to pass value from a fragment to another fragment. If so you should edit the question. Its saying you want to pass value from one activity to another. I am answering according to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intents to pass data between activities.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, Next.class);
intent.putExtra("itemid", item.getItemId());
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the other activity.

```
 String itemId= getIntent().getStringExtra("itemid");
 switch(itemId)
 {
   ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you...   I put inside switch case like this case R.id.action_settings:fragment = new SettingsFragment(); break;                  but i got error

Comment: As others said, you wanted to use fragments, mine would be activites.

Comment: I want what you gave.. but i got issue.. Please read my above comment

Comment: Umm I suggest you to debug and print which value is in the actual data, make sure that the new activity has the same options.xml, check the values for it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems you want to pass value from a fragment to another fragment. If so you should edit the question. Its saying you want to pass value from one activity to another. I am answering according to fragment.

Do this

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    case R.id.action_settings:
        SettingsFragment fragmentS = new SettingsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("ItemID", item.getItemId());
        fragmentS.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentS).commit();
        break;
}
```

In other fragment get the value like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int itemId = getArguments().getInt("ItemID");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to pass data to a fragment actually?

Try adding before strating a fragment transaction:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("id", tem.getItemId());
fragmentS.setArguments(bundle);
```